# Collapsing Toolbar Layout expand on click event

Tags: android, android-collapsingtoolbarlayout, android-appbarlayout

I have a simple toolbar with a title and a icon. What I want is that when the toolbar is clicked it expands and shows more fields to do a search with some filters. What I really would like is to have the same effect that the airbnb app has in the explore bar.

Can anyone show me how to handle this or give some tips?

What I currently have is this layout. But the collapsing toolbar overrides the toolbar int the top.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.ezycities.ezycities.ui.homehost.DisableableCoordinatorLayout 
    android:id="@+id/coordinator"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar android:id="@+id/toolbarUserProfilePage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/first_grey">

        <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewUserProfilePageToolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="25dp"
            android:layout_marginStart="25dp"
            android:maxLines="1"
            android:text="@string/userProfile.toolbar"
            android:textColor="@color/third_grey"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <ImageView android:id="@+id/imageViewUserProfilePageToolbar"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginEnd="20dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="end"
            android:tint="@color/third_grey" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark">

        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">

            <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewEditProfilePageLastName"
                android:layout_width="86dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/user.edit.last_name"
                style="@style/editProfilePageTitles" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewEditProfilePageLastName2"
                android:layout_width="86dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/user.edit.last_name"
                style="@style/editProfilePageTitles" />

            <TextView android:id="@+id/textViewEditProfilePageLastName3"
                android:layout_width="86dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
                android:layout_marginStart="20dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
                android:text="@string/user.edit.last_name"
                style="@style/editProfilePageTitles" />

        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

   <android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView android:id="@+id/scroll"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

   </android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>

</com.ezycities.ezycities.ui.homehost.DisableableCoordinatorLayout>
```

And in the class I use the setExpanded(true) and setExpanded(false) when I want to either expand or collapse the toolbar.

```
public class HomeHostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @BindView(R.id.coordinator) DisableableCoordinatorLayout collapsingToolbarLayout;
    @BindView(R.id.toolbarUserProfilePage) Toolbar toolbar;
    @BindView(R.id.appbar) AppBarLayout searchBarLayout;


   @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

       setContentView(R.layout.teste);

       ButterKnife.bind(this);

       collapsingToolbarLayout.setPassScrolling(false);
   }

   @OnClick(R.id.toolbarUserProfilePage)
   public void expandView(View view) {
       searchBarLayout.setExpanded(true, true);
   }

   @OnClick(R.id.textViewEditProfilePageLastName)
    public void collapseView(View view) {
        searchBarLayout.setExpanded(false, true);
   }

    @Override
    protected void attachBaseContext(Context newBase) {
        super.attachBaseContext(CalligraphyContextWrapper.wrap(newBase));
    }
```

Comment: why you are using two collapsing toolbars, remove one of that.
If you need different toolbar layout you can make layout under toolbar attributes and changes view ACC to your requirement.

Comment: @Harsh Mittal I'm just using one collapsing toolbar. I have a initial toolbar that when clicked expands the collapsing toolbar layout

Comment: Use that toolbar under appbar>collapsing toolbar layout.

Comment: But if I do like you're saying, the toolbar and the field that I want to show it will be both visible. I tried under the appbar, but when click doesn't have any effect.